# Apple's accepted PhoneGap version for iOS

Tags: iphone, cordova

I was thinking of cross platform support the easiest way, there were many answers, so thought of choosing "Phone Gap" out of it and use it. Have been reading about its previous issues with Apple.

And heard that still people are getting rejected for some version's of Phone gap. Some where in a blog read that apple recommends using stable versions. Which would be the apple accepted version? Or is there any issue still with Apple?

Could we use the latest build of Phone Gap with guarantee that iOS app wouldn't get rejected?

Could you please guide the correct version of "Phone Gap" used, which has successfully reached Apples app-store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the latest. which is 1.4.
it'll work for you.

Comment: Have you tried building app using the latest (1.4) and successfully posted to app store?

Comment: i built one using 1.3 and posted it happily :)